# cutom nex and pre slide button in swiper react do not work

Tags: reactjs, slider, swiper.js

i try to make custom button for swiper react and my component is here:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import styles from "./food.module.css";

// import required modules
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation } from "swiper";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/navigation";

const Food = () => {
  const nextRef = useRef();
  const preRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={5}
        spaceBetween={30}
        slidesPerGroup={5}
        loop={true}
        loopFillGroupWithBlank={true}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        navigation={{
          nextEl: nextRef.current,
          prevEl: preRef.current,
        }}
        modules={[Navigation]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p className={styles.p}>hello</p>
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <p className={styles.p}>hello</p>
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <p className={styles.p}>hello</p>
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <p className={styles.p}>hello</p>
        </SwiperSlide>

        <SwiperSlide>
          <p className={styles.p}>hello</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>

      <div ref={preRef}>previous</div>
      <div ref={nextRef}>next</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Food;
```

next and pre div do not work. how can fix it?
i make two ref for next and pre but it seems to not work in this way.
everything in slider is ok but just pre and next do not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `nextRef.current` and `prevRef.current` are undefined at the time of Swiper initialization.

The simplest solution might be to use class name:

```js
<Swiper
  ...
  navigation={{
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  }}
  modules={[Navigation]}
>...</Swiper>

<div className="swiper-button-prev">previous</div>
<div className="swiper-button-next">next</div>
```

Or you can still use useRef by re-initializing Swiper component after first render:

```js
const [swiperKey, setSwiperKey] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setSwiperKey(1);
}, []);

return (
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <Swiper
      key={swiperKey}
      ...
```